# Select largest number using pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I have the following expression:

```
myExpr=R[C[2],B].(II+R[C[3],C[2]].(II+R[C[4],C[3]]))
```

I need to create a pattern which would replace the `R[]` which holds the **largest** `C` (hence `R[C[4],C[3]]` in the above example) with `R[C[4],C[3]].(II+R[C[5],C[4]])`. I would like this process to repeat until the largest argument of `C[]` reaches some value, for example 7.

The pseudo-code for what I am looking for is below:

```
ReplaceRepeated[myExpr,{
    R[C[largest_/;largest<=7],anything__]->R[C[largest],anything].(II+R[C[largest+1],C[largest]])
}]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following appears to be what you want.

```
repl[expr_, max_] := 
 With[{largest = Max[Cases[expr, C[n_] :> n, Infinity]]},
  If[largest <= max, 
   expr /. (R[C[largest], anything__] :> 
    R[C[largest], anything].(II + R[C[largest + 1], C[largest]])) //
     repl,
  expr]
 ]

repl[myExpr, 7]
```

Alternative formulation if recursion doesn't float your boat:

```
largest[expr_] := Max[Cases[expr, C[n_] :> n, Infinity]]

With[{max = 7}, NestWhile[
 With[{l = largest[#]}, 
  # /. 
   R[C[l], anything__] :> 
   R[C[l], anything].(II + R[C[l + 1], C[l]])
 ] &,
 myExpr, 
 largest[#] <= max &]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Recrusion is perfectly fine. I'm just no understanding one thing: when you use `:=`, it seems like after I make a change to the definition of `repl` (for example I added an argument `MaxNum_` to replace the `7`), I press Shift+Enter on the `repl` cell, but the changes are not reflected when I execute some place using `repl` - do you know what might be wrong here?

Comment: You're adding to the `DownValues` of `repl` when you do that, not replacing them. You should `Clear[repl]` first, if it's a problem. It's good practice anyway to clear a symbol before you redefine it, just to make sure that things like this don't happen.

Comment: Here is what finally worked for me: `Clear[repl];
repl[expr_, maxFrame_] := 
 With[{largest = Max[Cases[expr, C[n_] :> n, Infinity]]},
  If[largest < maxFrame,
   repl[expr /. (R[C[largest], anything__] :> 
       R[C[largest], anything].(II + R[C[largest + 1], C[largest]])), 
    maxFrame],
   (* Otherwise *)
   expr
   ]
  ]` and you call using for example `repl[R[C[2], B].(II + R[C[3], C[2]]), 5]`. If you would like to update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind using `&` after some of your code, for example `largest[#] <= max &` and `With[...] &`. I'm trying to understand when it should be used.

Comment: See the docs under `Function`. `&` is a shorthand for `Function`.